# Exercise 9, Chapter 2 of Stein's Fourier Analysis. Showing that a fourier series does not converge absolutely but converges conditionally.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, conditional-convergence

Let $f(x)=\chi_{[a,b]}(x)$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[a,b]\subset [-\pi,\pi]$.

Show that if $a\neq -\pi$, or $b\neq \pi$ and $a\neq b$, then the Fourier series does not converge absolutely for any $x$. [Hint: It suffices to prove that for many values of $n$ one has $|\sin n\theta_0|\ge c \gt 0$ where $\theta_0=(b-a)/2.$]

However, prove that the Fourier series converges at every point $x$.

I've computed the Fourier series and got $\frac{b-a}{2\pi}+\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{e^{-ina}-e^{-inb}}{2\pi in}e^{inx}.$

Also, $|e^{-ina}-e^{-inb}|=2|\sin n\theta_0|$, and $\theta_0\in (0,\pi)$, so I can see that for infinitely many values of $n$, we have $|\sin n\theta_0|\ge c \gt 0$. But this does not guarantee $\sum_{n\neq 0}|\frac{e^{-ina}-e^{-inb}}{2\pi in}e^{inx}|\ge \sum \frac{c}{n}$, and in fact we might have this inequality only for the squares of integers, in which case the right hand side converges. So how does the hint solve the problem?

Moreover, for the second problem, to show that the Fourier series converges at every point, I think I need to use Dirichlet's test, using $1/n$ as the decreasing sequence to $0$, but how can I show that $\frac{e^{-ina}-e^{-inb}}{2\pi in}e^{inx}$ has bounded partial sums?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Notice that $|\sin(n\theta)|>c$ as long as $|n\theta-N|>\delta$ for every $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ and some fixed $\delta$. What does it happen if $\theta$ is rational? if it's irrational? For convergence, use the fact that ${1/n}$ decreases monotonically and that $\sum e^{in(x-a)}$ is bounded for $x\neq a$. If $x=a$, then $1/n-1/n=0$.

Comment: @user90189 Sorry I'm confused with your answer. Why do you consider $|n\theta - N|$ and why do you ignore $e^{-inb}$ in the series at the end? Can you clarify why $|\sin(n\theta)| > c$ as long as $|n\theta-N| > \delta$ for every $N$ and some fixed $\delta$?

Comment: @user90189 Also why do we have $1/n - 1/n =0$ if $x=a$? Shouldn't we have $\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{1-e^{in(a-b)}}{2\pi in}$?

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be $|n\theta-\pi N|>\delta$.  Since the sine function vanishes everytime it touches $\pi N$ for some $N$ integer, you should be away from it. Draw a graph, it may help you. Note that it suffices to prove convergence for $\sum_{n\neq 0}e^{iny}/n$, then if $y=0$, after grouping $\sum_{n\neq 0}1/n=(1-1)+(1/2-1/2)+\cdots+(1/N-1/N)$.

Comment: @user90189 I see your point, but how can I show that the sine function should be away rom $\pi N$, for every $N$ integer in such a case? How does considering $\theta$ rational and irrational help here?

Comment: Dear takecare, have you resolved your doubts about convergence? Do you see that given $\delta >0$ then $|\sin(t)|>c$ whenever $|t-\pi \mathbb{Z}|>\delta$ for sufficiently small $c$? Dividing by $\pi$ we need to check that $|nx-\mathbb{Z}|\ge\delta$ for some $\delta$ for many $n$, where $x$ isn't integer. Say $x=p/q$, $(p,q)=1$, then take $\delta=1/q$, what does it happen if $q|n$? if $q$ doesn't divide $n$? What does it happen if $x$ is irrational?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $a \ne -\pi$ or $b \ne \pi$ and $a\ne b$. Then the function you are talking about must be discontinuous.

Suppose the series did converge absolutely for some $x$. That would mean
$$
         \sum_n \left|\frac{e^{-ina}-e^{-inb}}{2\pi in}\right| < \infty.
$$
But that would force the *uniform* convergence of the Fourier series everywhere by the Weierstrass M-test. But uniform convergence would imply that the periodic extension of the limit function $\chi_{[a,b]}$ must be continuous everywhere, which only happens in the case that $a=-\pi$ and $b=\pi$, or $a=b$.

I'm not familiar with you text, but you should have some pointwise convergence theorem that shows the Fourier series converges to the mean of the left and right hand limits for your function.

Comment: This is better than the hint given in the book.

Comment: Hello. Here you are assuming that the Fourier series converges to $\chi_{[a,b]}$, which hasn't been proved (yet).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I like to write the Fourier coefficients of this function as
$$\widehat{\chi_{\left[a,b\right]}}\left(n\right)=\frac{b-a}{2\pi}\exp\left(-i\frac{a+b}{2}n\right)\mathrm{sinc}\left(\frac{b-a}{2\pi}n\right)$$ where $$\mathrm{sinc}\,\eta
= \frac{\sin \pi\eta}{\pi\eta},\qquad \mathrm{sinc}\,0=1.$$

It's quite easy to show that $\sum\widehat{\chi_{\left[a,b\right]}}\left(n\right)$ converges (although not absolutely), using the following lemma:

> **(Dirichlet Test; exercise 7b in chapter 2 of Stein & Shakarchi)** If the partial sums of $\sum b_n$ are bounded, and $a_0 \geqslant a_1 \geqslant\cdots\geqslant a_n \geqslant\cdots\to 0$, then $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

The proof of Dirichlet's Test is based on [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

To use this test, it's actually easier to write $\chi$ the way you did:
$$\chi_{\left[a,b\right]}\left(x\right) \sim \frac{b-a}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{
2\pi i}\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{e^{in\left(x-a\right)}
- e^{in\left(x-b\right)}}{n}.$$

This is a series of differences. It's enough to show that each of the series $\sum e^{in\left(x-a\right)}/n$ and $\sum e^{in\left(x-b\right)}/n$ converge, because then the Fourier series of $\chi$ can be constructed by just taking the difference between these two series (if two series converge, their sum-series and difference-series also converge). If you've done exercise 8 in this chapter, you'll know that you have to use Dirichlet's test by making $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=e^{in\theta}$, with $\theta=x-a$ or $x-b$. It's easy to show that the partials of $\sum e^{in\theta}$ are bounded. Just use the fact that it's a power series:
$$\left|\sum_{1}^{N-1}e^{inx}\right|=\left|\frac{1-e^{iNx}}{1-e^{ix}}-1\right|=\frac{\left|1-e^{i\left(N-1\right)x}\right|}{\left|1-e^{ix}\right|}
\leqslant\frac{2}{\left|1-e^{ix}\right|}$$
(This *is* an acceptable bound because $x$ is fixed.) (I did it just for $n>0$, but you can just do the same for $n<0$.)

Now, there's actually two senses in which the Fourier series of $\chi$ could converge absolutely. First, you look at the *complex* Fourier series, and ask whether the following series converges:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|\widehat{\chi_{\left[a,b\right]}}\left(n\right)e^{inx}\right|\to\,?$$
Showing that it does not converge is reasonably doable. Now, what's interesting is to ask whether the *real* Fourier series (that is, the series of sinusoids, instead of the series of complex exponentials) converges absolutely. We can re-write it (yes, again) like this:
$$\frac{b-a}{2\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{1}{n}\left|\sin\left(\frac{b-a}{2}n\right)\right|\cdot\left|\cos\left(\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)n\right)\right|
\to ?$$
You can show show that it does not converge (with the exception that, if $b-a=\pi$, then it converges trivially on $x=b$ and $x=a$). I won't go into all of the details, because I can't seem to find an easy, quick proof (it would actually be quite tedious if I detailed all of it), but I'll do my best.

Let $\theta_{0}=\left(b-a\right)/2$ e $\omega=x-\left(a+b\right)/2$. We want to show that $\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{1}{n}\sin n\theta_{0}\cos n\omega$ is not absolutely convergent. The strategy is the obvious one: show that $\left|\sin n\theta_0\right|\geqslant c>0$ more than 50% of the time, and show the same for $\left|\cos n\omega\right|$. Then, by the pigeonhole principle, we'll have
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sin n\theta_{0}\cos n\omega\right|\geqslant\frac{c^2}{n}$$ at least once per period, which is enough to compare $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\left|\sin n\theta_{0}\right|\cdot\left|\cos n\omega\right|/n$ to the harmonic series.]

Let's start by getting out of the way the case in which both $\theta_0$ and $\omega$ are rational multiples pf $\pi$. Let $\theta_0=\left(p/q\right)2\pi$, with $p/q$ already in lowest terms. Then $n\theta_{0}$ is periodic with period $q$ and assumes all values $$\frac{0}{q},\frac{1}{q},\frac{2}{q},\cdots,\frac{q-1}{q}$$ in each period. We're interested in the sequence $\sin n\theta_{0}$. We know that $q\geqslant 3$, since $\theta_{0}\in\left]0,\pi\right[$. Also, let $\omega=\left(r/s\right)2\pi$ with $r/s$ in lowest terms, so that $n\omega$ has period $s$.

If $q=3$, then $\left|\sin n\theta_{0}\right|$ spends $2/3$ of the time being equal to $\sqrt{3}/2$. If $q=4$, the sequence $\left|\sin n\theta_{0}\right|$ is $1,0,1,0,\ldots$. If $q\geqslant 5$, then $\left|\sin n\theta_{0}\right|$ has period $5$ and is zero at most twice per period, and therefore is greater than its minimum more than 50% of the time. As to $\omega$, it's also easy to see that the sequence $\left|\cos n\omega\right|$ is also $\geqslant c>0$ more than 50% of the time, unless $s=4$.

That's enough to show that, unless $q=s=4$, the sequence $\left|\sin n\theta_{0}\cos n\omega\right|$ is periodic with period $qs$, and by the pigeonhole principle there's at least one non-zero element per period. Let's say that this non-zero element is the $k$-th:
$$\forall d\geqslant0\text{,} \left|\sin\left(dqs+k\right)\theta_{0}\cos\left(dqs+k\right)\omega\right|
 =\left|\sin k\theta_{0}\cos k\omega\right|>0\text{.}$$
Then:
$$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{1}{n}\left|\sin n\theta_{0}\cos n\omega\right|\geqslant\left|\sin k\theta_{0}\cos k\omega\right|\sum_{d\geqslant1}\frac{1}{dqs+k}=\infty\text{,}$$
and we're good, unless $q=s=4$.

When $q=s=4$, the series is actually absolutely convergent in a trivial fashion: all of its terms are zero, because $\left|\sin\right|$ will be $0,1,0,1,\ldots$ and $\left|\cos\right|$ will be $1,0,1,0,\ldots$. Well, $q=4$ means $\theta_{0}=\pi/2$, which means $b-a=\pi$; and $s=4$ means $\omega=\pm\pi/2$, meaning $x=a$ or $x=b$.

Now, the case in which $\theta_0$ or $\omega$ are irrational multiples of $\pi$ is the tedious part. (Actually, we could use the equidistribution theorem here, but that'll only show up in chapter 3 of the book! We'll try to do without it.) Let $H$ be the set of angles $\theta$ for which $\left|\sin\theta\right|<\sin\left(\pi/50\right)$. Also, let $H'$ be the set of $\theta$ such that $\left|\cos\theta\right|<\sin\left(\pi/50\right)$. $H$ and $H'$ together make up 8% of the whole circle, so we'd expect that any reasonable periodic-ish sequence in the the circle ends up outside of $H\cup H'$ around 92% of the time.

Let's say that a finite sequence $\Theta_{p}\left(N_{0}\right)=\left\{ N_{0}\theta,\left(N_{0}+1\right)\theta,\ldots,\left(N_{0}+p\right)\theta\right\}$ is *reasonably  well-distributed* in the circle (rwd for short) when $\Theta$ has more than 50% of its elements *outside* $H$, and also more than 50% *outside* $H'$. I'll start by showing the following result:

> Let $\theta\in\left]0,\pi/3\right[\setminus\pi\mathbb{Q}$. There exists $p\geqslant 1$ such that, given any $x_{0}\notin\pi\mathbb{Q}$, the finite set
>   $$\Theta=\left\{ x_{0},x_{0}+\theta,\ldots,x_{0}+p\theta\right\} $$
>   is rwd.

Well, since $\theta\in\left]0,\pi/3\right[\setminus\pi\mathbb{Q}$, there is $p\in\mathbb{Z},p\geqslant6$ such that
$$\frac{2\pi}{p+1}<\theta<\frac{2\pi}{p},\qquad\text{i.e.,}\qquad p\theta<2\pi<\left(p+1\right)\theta\text{.}$$
Let $x_0\notin\pi\mathbb Q$. We want to show that, out of all of the $p+1$ elements in $\Theta$, *more* than $\left(p+1\right)/2$ are *outside* $H$. Well, it's not very hard to show that, since the elements in $\Theta$ are equally spaced (except for the pair $x_0$ and $x_0+p\theta$, which could be quite close to each other by roing around the circle), the number of elements in $\Theta\cap H$ is:
$$\#\left(\Theta\cap H\right)\leqslant 2\left\lceil \frac{2\pi/50}{\theta}\right\rceil +1\text{.}$$
Now, we plug in $\theta>2\pi/\left(p+1\right)$ and $p\geqslant6$ to find that
$$\#\left(\Theta\cap H\right)<\frac{p+1}{2}=\frac{\#\Theta}{2}\text{.}$$
(Yes, that "50" in there was important; I didn't just "make up a huge number" when designing $H$ and $H'$. We need that 50 because it makes the inequality $2\left\lceil \frac{p+1}{50}\right\rceil +1<\frac{p+1}{2}$ valid for $p\geqslant 6$.)

Anyway, ok, we showed that for $H$, and the proof is exactly the same for $H'$, so $\Theta$ is rwd, as promised.

Moving on, we'd like to show the same proposition above without the restriction $\theta\in\left]0,\pi/3\right[$. However, we already know that $\theta=\pi/2$ is a problem, and that will make $\theta\approx\pi/2$ a problem too. We'll write $\theta=\pi/2-\vartheta$, with $\vartheta\in\left]0,\pi/6\right[\setminus\pi\mathbb{Q}$ and abuse the formulas: $$\left|\sin n\theta\right| =\begin{cases}
\left|\sin n\vartheta\right|, & n\text{ even}\\
\left|\cos n\vartheta\right|, & n\text{ odd}
\end{cases}\text{; and}$$
$$\left|\cos n\theta\right| =\begin{cases}
\left|\cos n\vartheta\right|, & n\text{ even}\\
\left|\sin n\vartheta\right|, & n\text{ odd}
\end{cases}$$

> Let $\theta\in\left]\pi/3,\pi/2\right[\setminus\pi\mathbb{Q}$. There exists $p\geqslant1$ such that, given any $N_{0}\in\mathbb{Z}$, the finite set $$\Theta=\left\{ N_{0}\theta,\left(N_{0}+2\right)\theta,\ldots,\left(N_{0}+2p\right)\theta\right\}$$ is rwd.

Ok, let $\vartheta=\pi/2-\theta$ so that $2\vartheta\in\left]0,\pi/3\right[$ and using the first proposition above, $\left\{ x_{0},x_{0}+2\vartheta,\ldots,x_{0}+2p\vartheta\right\}$ is rwd for all $x_0$. Letting $x_{0}=N_{0}\vartheta,N_0\in\mathbb Z$, we get that $\left\{ N_{0}\vartheta,\left(N_{0}+2\right)\vartheta,\ldots,\left(N_{0}+2p\right)\vartheta\right\} $ is rwd. By considering the cases $N_0$ even and $N_0$ odd separately, we show that we can change $\vartheta$ for $\theta$ in this set, and the elements inside $H$ remain inside $H$ (or, if $N_0$ is odd, become elements of $H'$ and vice-versa). Anyway, it's proved.

Even though that second proposition above looks like it doesn't help much, it does:

> Let $\theta\in\left]0,\pi/2\right[\setminus\pi\mathbb{Q}$. There exists $p\geqslant1$ such that, given any $N_{0}\in\mathbb{Z}$, the finite set $\Theta_{p}\left(N_{0}\right)$ is rwd.

We just have to show for $\theta\in\left]\pi/3,\pi/2\right[\setminus\pi\mathbb{Q}$, because the other case is already contemplated in the first proposition above. Applying the second proposition, we get $p'\geqslant 1$ such that $\Theta=\left\{ N_{0}\theta,\left(N_{0}+2\right)\theta,\ldots,\left(N_{0}+p'\right)\theta\right\}$ is rwd for any $N_0$. Now, let $p=2p'+1$. Given any $N_0$, the set $\Theta_{p}\left(N_{0}\right)=\left\{ N_{0}\theta,\left(N_{0}+1\right)\theta,\ldots,\left(N_{0}+p\right)\theta\right\}$ can be partitioned into two sets of size $p'+1$: one with the even multiples of $N_0$, and the other with the odd multiples. Both partitions are rwd, and therefore their union also is.

Now, we extend this result to $\theta\in\left]0,\pi\right[$ using the relevant trigonometric identities again, and then extend it, finally, to the whole circle:

> Let $\theta\notin\pi\mathbb{Q}$. There exists $p\geqslant1$ such that given any $N_{0}$, $\Theta_{p}\left(N_{0}\right)$ is rwd.

I'm translating this from my notes in portuguese from [when I was taking this course](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833933/sum-left-sin-alpha-n-sin-beta-n-right-n-infty-when-alpha-neq-beta) (all of that LaTeX was already typed!), and I'm getting tired of writing, so I hope you can see that this last result is enough to tackle the cases in which each of $\theta_0$ or $\omega$ or both are irrational multiples of $\pi$. By the way, those notes were typed  using the notation [$\tau=2\pi$](https://tauday.com/), and in the process of translating from portuguese I also translated from tau, and I might have forgotten to double or halve some of the integers above, so double-check everything if you're going to use it for real.

Answer (score 2):

I see that both of the previous answers to part (b) of this exercise do not fully use the hint in the statement, so I'll attempt to do so. For part (c), the first few paragraphs of [fonini's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3021029/820746) should suffice.

We need to show that the series
$$
\sum_{n\ne0} \left| \frac{e^{-ina}-e^{-inb}}{2\pi in} e^{inx} \right|
$$
converges. Rewriting the expression in terms of $\theta_0=(b-a)/2$ by factoring out $e^{-in\frac{1}{2}(a+b)}$ and recalling that $|e^{in\varphi}|=1$ for any $\varphi$ gives us
$$
\sum_{n\ne0} \left| \frac{\sin n\theta_0}{\pi n} \right|
  = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin n\theta_0|}{n},
$$
since the value of the argument of the sum does not change if $n\to-n$.

**Now comes the part of the proof where we use the 'for many values of $n$ one has …' part of the hint.** To prove convergence, it suffices to show that in a *countably infinite* number of terms, $|\sin n\theta_0| \ge c > 0$, for if so, the sum of all these terms diverges by comparison with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c}{n}$, which, in turn, implies divergence of our expression by comparison with this smaller series (insert zeroes in between the terms of the smaller series so that the identical terms in both series have the same index, i.e. match up).

To do this, we show that, for all integers $k>0$, we can choose another integer $n_k>0$ such that the desired property holds when $n=n_k$, dependent upon the value of $k$. First note that $0<\theta_0<\pi$, so there exists $0<c<1$ such that $\pi-\theta_0 < 2 \arcsin c$. (*The choice of $2\arcsin c$ in favour of $\arcsin c$ is done to facilitate the key argument below.*) We claim that, for each $k$, there exists a positive integer $n_k$ such that
$$
n_k\theta_0 \in \big( (k-1)\pi + \arcsin c , k\pi - \arcsin c \big),
$$
the interval on the right hand side we denote as $I_k$. For if so, we have $(k-1)\pi + \arcsin c < n_k\theta_0 < k\pi - \arcsin c$, **which may be rearranged to give the desired condition**. (Note that $|\sin(n_k\theta_0-(k-1)\pi)|=|\sin(n_k\theta_0-k\pi)|=|\sin(n_k\theta_0)|$.)

The claim can be proved as follows. (It helps to have a sketch of $y=|\sin x|$ on hand and draw on it as you read this argument.) Since $\theta_0<\pi$, it is obvious (by contradiction; simple exercise) that, for all $k$, each interval $((k-1)\pi,k\pi)$ includes at least one $n\theta_0$. Now there are two cases: either $n\theta_0 \in I_k$ or $n\theta_0 \notin I_k$. In the first case, we are done, and can set $n_k=n$. In the second case, either $n\theta_0 \in ((k-1)\pi, (k-1)\pi+\arcsin c)$ or $n\theta_0 \in (k\pi-\arcsin c, k\pi)$. But since $|I_k|>n_k\theta_0$, in the first subcase $(n+1)\theta_0 \in I_k$ (so $n_k=n+1)$, whereas in the second subcase $(n-1)\theta_0 \in I_k$ (so $n_k=n-1$), and we are also done. (*Now you should be able to see why we chose $2\arcsin c$.*) Therefore, each interval $((k-1)\pi,k\pi)$ (the number of which is countably infinite) can be assigned to an integer $n_k$, so we conclude that there are infinitely many $n_k$, such that if $n$ does not satisfy our desired condition, then either $n-1$ or $n+1$ will, i.e. there cannot be consecutive values of $n$ which do not satisfy the condition. We conclude that, in the worst case scenario where the $n_k$ are most sparsely distributed, either the $n_k$ are all the odd positive integers or $n_k$ are all the even positive integers. If we take the reciprocal of each and sum over each collection separately, both diverge (since they are related to the harmonic series).

Thus there exists an infinite number of $n_k$ such that $|\sin n_k\theta_0| \ge c$, enumerated by the positive integers $k$. This implies that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin n\theta_0|}{n}
  \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin n_k\theta_0|}{n_k}
  \ge \sum_{n\,\text{odd}} \frac{c}{n} \to +\infty,
$$
by the arguments presented in paragraph 3. We are done.

[Note: The book claims to assume very few prerequisites, so in all candour, I don't know why the authors assigned this as Exercise 9(b) in a collection of 20 exercises without more hints, since this argument is somewhat intricate.]

Comment: It's not enough to just have infinitely many $n_k$, since they can grow quickly (so that you're essentially comparing with $n^{-2}$ or worse).  It's crucial that the $n_k$ you found grow linearly so that you still get a diverging sequence.

Comment: $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$ famouly converges though primes are countably infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume, by way of contradiction, that this series converges:
$$\sum_{n\not=0} \frac{|e^{-na}+e^{-nb}|}{2\pi n}=\sum_{n\not=0}\frac{|\sin(n\theta_o)|}{\pi |n|}$$

We observe that due to our hypothesis that $-\pi < a < b \leq \pi$, the difference between $a$ and $b$ satisfies $0 < b - a < 2\pi$, which implies $0 < \theta_o < \pi$. When we state that the series converges, we are actually referring to taking the symmetric limit. This means that the partial sum denoted by $S_m$ converges:

$$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{2|\sin(n\theta)|}{\pi n}$$

In particular the subsequence $S_{2m}$ but we may write this as:

$$S_{2m}=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{2}{\pi }\left(\frac{|\sin(2n-1)\theta_o)|}{2n-1}+\frac{|\sin(2n\theta_o)|}{2n}\right)\geq \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{\pi n}(|\sin(2n-1)\theta_o|+|\sin(2n\theta_o)|)$$

Let us investigate the conditions under which $g(x) = |\sin((2x-1)\theta_o)| + |\sin(2x\theta_o)| = 0$. This can only happen if both terms inside the sine functions are integer multiples of $\pi$, but this would imply that $\theta_o$ is a multiple of $\pi$, contradicting the specified range it belongs to. Consequently, $g(x)$ can never be zero. Since it has a periodicity of $\pi/\theta_o$, we can focus on the interval $[0, \pi/\theta_o]$, which is compact. We can then find the infimum of the function's range (which is achieved). Thus, we conclude that $g(x) > c$. Due to the periodic nature of $g(x)$, this lower bound must hold everywhere. As a result:

$$S_{2m}\geq \sum_{n=1}^m\frac{c}{\pi n}$$

This leads to an absurdity.